# What are the units of the channels in the result of readWave() in the tuneR package?

Tags: r, tuner

I am beginning to process my own .wav files, but am confused about the resulting object of the `readWave()` function in the `tuneR` package. The following basic walkthrough is a good reference for answering my inquiry:

http://samcarcagno.altervista.org/blog/basic-sound-processing-r/?doing_wp_cron=1527373182.3890509605407714843750

The values in the left channel piece of the output of the `readWave()` function get converted in this example. I'm interested in learning the original units as well as the ending units after this conversion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the author answered this question in the comments of the same page you link to:

> The unit of measurement is arbitrary. If you play out the WAV file the
>   actual RMS level will depend on your equipment (soundcard, volume
>   settings on your computer, speakers/headphones, etc…), so there is
>   little point trying to attach an absolute measurement unit to the
>   amplitude values of the waveform.